# Codename One - drawing aberration between components even without any margin

Tags: styles, codenameone

I am experiencing a drawing aberration of one or two pixels between components, in which the background shines through. The margins of the involved components is 0, so there should be no gap of anything shining through.

To illustrate: a simple Form having a background image, a content container with white background and the southern component of the toolbar is having a rounded image, also in white, to have a visually appealing separation between the toolbar and the content:
[image]

As seen in the second illustration, in special cases, there is a thin line drawn between the toolbar and the content container, which has a horrible visual impact.

To reproduce:

1. when swiping from the top within the toolbar downwards into the content container, the line briefly appears, while swiping over the white rounded image.
2. when swiping from the content container upwards into the toolbar, the line appears and stays.

I assumed this has something to do with the unselected/selected/pressed UIID styles, however I copied the unselected styles everywhere with the same 0 margin and it didnt change anything.

here is the minimal code to reproduce:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    addToolbar(hi);
    addContent(hi);
    hi.show();
}

private void addToolbar(Form hi) {
    Toolbar toolbar = hi.getToolbar();
    toolbar.setUIID("Container");
    toolbar.setTitle("Title");

    Label divider = new Label(" ", "ToolbarDivider");
    toolbar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, divider);

    Label spacer = new Label(" ", "ToolbarSpacer");
    toolbar.add(BorderLayout.EAST, spacer);
}

private void addContent(Form hi) {
    Container whiteContainer = new Container();
    whiteContainer.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    whiteContainer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    whiteContainer.add(new Label("content"));

    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, whiteContainer);
}
```

Note: ToolbarDivider is a style to have the white rounded image as background with zero margins and paddings. Toolbar Spacer is having a top margin which is added to the right of the toolbar to make it bigger and more appealing (my app has more content to show in the toolbar).

Any help in why this line is occurring would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes I have similar issues in the Simulator only, while on real devices it's all fine. Do you have this problem in the Simulator or in real devices or in both?

Comment: Make sure to enable scrolling on the simulator to see an accurate representation. You shouldn't add components into the `Toolbar` as it can cause adverse effects. You should use padding instead of adding a component to increase size. If this persists I suggest using the component inspector to try and round up suspects for this line.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog To enable scrolling on the simulator, do you mean to click on "Simulate" and then on "Zoom"?

Comment: Thank you Francesco and Shai. 
1. yesterday I had issues with my build link so I couldnt test on the device. Today I could and I found that the issue is limited to the simulator.
2. using "Enable Scrolling" in the simulator enlarges the simulator by a lot which allows for accurate painting. This way, the issue is in fact gone.
@Shai: I used the inspector several times and noted nothing else there. I used the EAST component padding to have a consistent Toolbar height across my forms and it works well so far.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani no. Scrolling needs to be checked. It removes any scaling of the skin and thus removes potential artifacts that are a result of the scaling process.